# Videojs Poster Image Does not Display - Need Poster Image to Display when Device Doesn't allow Auto Play

Tags: iphone, fallback, autoplay, video.js, poster

I have a website with a video in the header that is set to auto play when the page loads. It works great on all web browsers except for iPhone and iPad.  I recently discovered that the iPhone won't allow auto play, which explains why when I open it up on the iPhone there is a black box with a line through the play button where the video should be.  I can't even get it to load on the iPad.  I haven't been able to test on Android or the other mobile devices since I don't own any of them. Btw: I am using Video.js.

Here's what I'm trying to do and need some help: Since my video has to auto play, I want to have the poster image display rather than the video if a particular device like the iPhone won't allow auto play.  Is this possible?? I tried, but I can't get the poster image to show though.  Instead, it just shows that ugly black box with play button with a line through it.  I need help getting the poster image to display instead.  I thought this would happen automatically but it isn't.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I even wondered if there's a way to write a fallback statement that says something like this: "If no auto play then display image." I've seen fallback statements for Flash, so why not have one for a device that doesn't allow auto play. I'm trying to get the code right, but I'm not a php expert so I need some help.  Your help is appreciated thank you.